# Can I use external stepper motor power and USB connection

Tags: ramps-1.4, stepper-driver, usb

I have a RAMPS 1.4 with Arduino Mega 2560 with 2 steppers connected to an external power supply using Polulo stepper drivers. The steppers are for X and Y axis movement. This external power supply is set to 12 volts and power is applied. I have configured the marlin firmware also.

Can I connect my setup to my PC using USB when the external power is also on?
If i connect the USB while the external power is off, do the motors take power from USB? Will this will burn my board?

Comment: Is possible that you can burn the USB port and or your steppers can't work due lack of power of the same port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motors are powered from 12/24V external power supply, so the motors will not be powered. 
the ramps [Schematics](https://download.lulzbot.com/AO-100/hardware/electronics/RAMPS_1.4/RAMPS_1-4manual.pdf) shows the connection diagram and the power is provided via the VMot pin/12V.

[image: Stepper diagram]

Comment: Is it possible to select V in pin on arduino in place of 5 volt pin as logic power supply for motor driver?for how many drivers ,the 5 volt pin can be used as logic power supply on arduino?

Comment: is possible, but you need a driver (switch) to change the source from 5V USB to External 9-24V.